# How to build customise repository in springboot for microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot

how to design your own customise repository in Java springboot for micro services Get Api which will take one or n number of parameter define in request object

For eg:
search/user?will give all user details
search/user?name=john  will give data only have name with have john
Search/user?name=john&salary=100 will give specific data to name and salary
search/user?name=john&salary=100&add=china will give specific record to name salary and address

Same way the this one Url search/user will take one or n number of define request object in it so that this single Api will give output json objects as per the inputs provided

below is my code and the error i am getting in joining a query

Mobile Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MOBILE")
public class Mobile implements Serializable {

//Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Mobile.class);

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "brand")
private String brand;

@Column(name = "phone")
private String phone;

@Column(name = "picture")
private String picture;

@Column(name = "sim")
private String sim;

@Column(name = "resolution")
private String resolution;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name ="hardware_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
private Hardware hardware;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="releases_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
private Releases releases;
```

Hardware Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Hardware")
public class Hardware implements Serializable {

//Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Hardware.class);

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name="audioJacks")
private String audioJacks;

@Column(name = "gps")
private String gps;


@Column(name = "battery")
private String battery;
enter code here
```

Releases Entity class

```
enter code here
 @Entity
 @Table(name="Releases")
 public class Releases implements Serializable {

 //Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Releases.class);



 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private long id;

 @Column(name="priceEuro")
 private long priceEuro;

 @Column(name="announceDate")
 private String announceDate;
```

Repoimplementation

```
  @Repository
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public class UserRepositoryCustomizedImpl implements UserRepoCustom {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public List<UserInformation> search(Map<String, String> requestMap) {

    if(requestMap!=null && requestMap.isEmpty()) {
    }

  //Below commented all the query i tried i got the error for all it is query which is wrong i am writing help me with the write query :)



    //String qry="Select m.brand,m.phone,m.picture,h.audioJacks,h.gps from 
com.example.users.m.hardware_id.Mobile m inner join 
com.example.users.entities.Hardware h where m.hardware_id=h.id ";
    //SELECT DISTINCT e FROM Employee e INNER JOIN e.tasks t
    //String qry="select m from Mobile m inner join m.hardware h";
    String qry="Select m.brand from Mobile m inner join m.hardware_id h 
where h.id=m.hardware_id";
System.out.println("Query is "+ qry);

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(qry,Hardware.class);

    return query.getResultList();
  }

}
```

Comment: When asking homework type questions, show your best good faith attempt to solve it and tell what problems you are having. This will give us a better understanding of what you're trying to do, what you might be doing wrong, and what you need help with. Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help), the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask), sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: yes i am new to stack overflow and this is not homework question i have build the api but i Dnt knw how to build one api which will fullfill my all get request...i have numbers of api which is not good way to write code so I ask in better way i can m not a good English speaker

Comment: If you built an api, then please `show your best good faith attempt to solve it and tell what problems you are having.`

Comment: @FailingCoder have added the code please help me with the query if you can i tried various query but i am facing issue in joining

Comment: error:"org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: hardware_id of: com.example.users.entities.Mobile [Select m.brand from com.example.users.entities.Mobile m inner join m.hardware_id h where h.id=m.hardware_id AND sim = 'Single Sim']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: hardware_id of: com.example.users.entities.Mobile [Select m.brand from com.example.users.entities.Mobile m inner join m.hardware_id h where h.id=m.hardware_id AND sim = 'Single Sim']",

Answer (score 0):

> String qry="Select m.brand from Mobile m inner join m.hardware_id h where h.id=m.hardware_id";

You are referring to `hardware_id` as the join property (assuming it as the join column name)

You should instead use the property name of the attribute in the Entity class. i.e. `hardware`

Comment: still i am getting the same error   this is what i got on console:rg.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: hardware_id of: com.example.users.entities.Mobile

Comment: my bad, i gave you the wrong suggestion earlier, corrected the answer

Comment: its ok... but i am still confuse what will be the right query as i want data from both the table mobile and hardware where as hardware id is foreign key in mobile table... i tried several search and apply the ways but still they same

Comment: Ah, then you just need 
String qry="Select m from Mobile m";

Since you are using JPA, refer https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbup for JPQL syntax

Comment: this is not working as well.will you please look into my entity class in code then you will get idea..even i used this one :( select m.brand, m.phone from mobile m,hardware h where m.hardware_id=h.id ) in mysql it is working fine but in JPQL it is giving error :( ...org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: mobile is not mapped